# Python find element from list of dict in other list of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two list of dict.

```
    students = [{'lastname': 'JAKUB', 'id': '92051048757', 'name': 'BAJOREK'}, 
{'lastname': 'MARIANNA', 'id': '92051861424', 'name': 'SLOTARZ'}, {'lastname':
 'SZYMON', 'id': '92052033215', 'name': 'WNUK'}, {'lastname': 'WOJCIECH', 'id':
 '92052877491', 'name': 'LESKO'}]
```

And

```
house = [{'id_pok': '2', 'id': '92051048757'}, {'id_pok': '24', 'id': '92051861424'}]
```

How to find elements that not exist in house list of dict matching by `id`?

Output

```
output = [{'lastname':
 'SZYMON', 'id': '92052033215', 'name': 'WNUK'}]
```

I try do that

```
for student in students:

    for home in house:

        if student['id'] != home['id']:

            print student
```

But this only repeat list

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i think output will contain id 92052033215 and 92052877491 right?

Comment: @Hackaholic yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that if there's any `house_id` which doesn't match a `student_id`, the `student` will be printed. You'd need some more logic or the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
for student in students:
    if not any (student['id'] == home['id'] for home in house):
        print(student)
```

It outputs:

```
{'lastname': 'SZYMON', 'id': '92052033215', 'name': 'WNUK'}
{'lastname': 'WOJCIECH', 'id': '92052877491', 'name': 'LESKO'}
```

A more efficient solution would be to keep a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) of house_ids, and find students whose id isn't included in this set:

```
students = [{'lastname': 'JAKUB', 'id': '92051048757', 'name': 'BAJOREK'},
{'lastname': 'MARIANNA', 'id': '92051861424', 'name': 'SLOTARZ'}, {'lastname':
 'SZYMON', 'id': '92052033215', 'name': 'WNUK'}, {'lastname': 'WOJCIECH', 'id':
 '92052877491', 'name': 'LESKO'}]

house = [{'id_pok': '2', 'id': '92051048757'}, {'id_pok': '24', 'id': '92051861424'}]

house_ids = set(house_dict['id'] for house_dict in house)
result = [student for student in students if student['id'] not in house_ids]
```

`print(result)`

It outputs:

```
[{'lastname': 'SZYMON', 'id': '92052033215', 'name': 'WNUK'}, {'lastname': 'WOJCIECH', 'id': '92052877491', 'name': 'LESKO'}]
```

Note that 2 students match your description.

The reason `set`[enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) is used is that it allows much faster lookup than a list.

Comment: you dont need to use `set`, i  think id must be unique

Comment: Using a set is a good way of checking the symmetric difference between two sets of data.

Comment: @Hackaholic: The reason I use `set` is not because it ensures unique ids, but because it allows fast lookup. With  a list, it would be much less efficient.

Comment: @EricDuminil can I add this print to list?

Comment: @lukassz: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean add output to list eg. `result = []` `result.append([student for student in students if student['pesel'] not in house_ids])`

Answer (score 0):

```
student_ids = set(d.get('id') for d in students)
house_ids = set(d.get('id') for d in house)

ids_not_in_house = student_ids ^ house_ids
```

Comment: I'm sure he can find a way to put 2 and 2 together

Answer (score 0):

```
students = [{'lastname': 'JAKUB', 'id': '92051048757', 'name': 'BAJOREK'}, 
{'lastname': 'MARIANNA', 'id': '92051861424', 'name': 'SLOTARZ'}, {'lastname':
 'SZYMON', 'id': '92052033215', 'name': 'WNUK'}, {'lastname': 'WOJCIECH', 'id':
 '92052877491', 'name': 'LESKO'}]

house = [{'id_pok': '2', 'id': '92051048757'}, {'id_pok': '24', 'id': '92051861424'}]

s = {item['id'] for item in students}
h = {item['id'] for item in house}

not_in_house_ids = s.difference(h)
not_in_house_items = [x for x in students if x['id'] in not_in_house_ids]
print (not_in_house_items)

>>>[{'name': 'WNUK', 'lastname': 'SZYMON', 'id': '92052033215'}, {'name': 'LESKO', 'lastname': 'WOJCIECH', 'id': '92052877491'}]
```